# Проблема с поиском

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-search-view

Написал простой блокнот, но после того, как я находил слово по поиску и нажимал на него открывалось другое слово. Как это исправить?

Вот исходный код
**MainActivity.java**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    static ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<>();

    static ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                ArrayList<String> templist = new ArrayList<>();

                for (String temp : notes){
                    if (temp.toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())){
                        templist.add(temp);
                    }

                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, templist);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.add_note_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.add_note){

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteEditor.class);

            startActivity(intent);


            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.nikita.mozhaev.notepad", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        HashSet<String> set = (HashSet<String>) sharedPreferences.getStringSet("notes", null);

        if (set == null){
            notes.add("Добавите новые слова!");
        }else{

            notes = new ArrayList<>(set);

        }



        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteEditor.class);
                intent.putExtra("noteId", i);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {

                final int itemToDelete = i;

                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setIcon(R.drawable.bin).setTitle("Вы уверены?")
                        .setMessage("Вы точно хотите удалить это слово?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {

                                notes.remove(itemToDelete);
                                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.nikita.mozhaev.notepad", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                                HashSet<String> set = new HashSet(MainActivity.notes);

                                sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes", set).apply();

                            }
                        }
                        ).setNegativeButton("Нет", null).show();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**NoteEditor.java**

```
import androidx.annotation.MainThread;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class NoteEditor extends AppCompatActivity {

    int noteId;

    Button btn_add;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);

        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext);

        btn_add = findViewById(R.id.btn_add);

        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        noteId = intent.getIntExtra("noteId", -1);

        if (noteId != -1){

            editText.setText(MainActivity.notes.get(noteId));

        }else{

            MainActivity.notes.add("");
            noteId = MainActivity.notes.size() -1;
            MainActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {

                MainActivity.notes.set(noteId, String.valueOf(charSequence));
                MainActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.nikita.mozhaev.notepad", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                HashSet<String> set = new HashSet(MainActivity.notes);

                sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes", set).apply();


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Правильным решением будет завести у объекта записи свое, уникальное id, передавать ее во второе окно и искать объект в списке с этим id

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

           note = listView.getItemAtPosition(pos);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteEditor.class);
            intent.putExtra("noteId", note.id); 
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

После чего надо найти этот элемент с таким id, проще всего это сделать через for

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (myList.get(i).getId() == id) {
        item = myList.get(i);
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: А в каком методе и где конкретно мне добавить for?

Comment: @nikita_game Там где ты используешь переданный id, конкретно в NoteEditor

Comment: а после, каких строк мне это прописать? Заранее спасибо, за ответ.

Comment: После этой строки?
if (noteId != -1){